# how to include a file in your hosting app for a cocoapod File

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have a private cocoapod to share common models and controllers at our company. There is a config file that needs to be included because it 
is referenced in the Cocoapod file. For example, if we have:

```
sample-proj/Pods/OurClasses/Classes/MyViewController.m
```

which has

```
#import "ABCConfig.h"
```

and ABCConfig is in `sample-proj`, how would I tell it to include it correctly? We have a project for which this works correctly and I thought
  it would adding $(SRCROOT) in Search Paths -> User Header Search Paths but this doesn't seem to do it (although this could be some wierd Xcode artefact).

Answer (score 0):

I can infer the problem as specifying a set of config to the libarary/framework. You should rethink of how you set a config and `import "ABCConfig.h" is right or not. There are couple of options,

1. Modify config file after you do pod install (this will be lost with next pod install),
2. use different config as submodule and import corresponding module when installing pods
3. Expose an API to feed in the configuration to library (best approach - flexible for user to tweak and give their configuration).

Comment: we already do #3 where we also have separate plist files. That works fine but there are more complex config options that are not easily handled by this. It seems as if the Header Search Path is the key parameter in Target Build Settings.